# convert json data to data frame in R

Tags: r

I have this data:

```
x<-c("{\"data\": [{\"target\": \"cpu\", \"datapoints\": [[5, 1423825200000.0], [10, 1423825500000.0], [3, 1423825800000.0], [20, 1423826100000.0], [15, 1423826400000.0], [50, 1423826700000.0], [11, 1423827000000.0], [50, 1423827300000.0], [60, 1423827600000.0], [50, 1423827900000.0], [60, 1423828200000.0], [10, 1423828500000.0], [100, 1423828800000.0], [20, 1423829100000.0], [40, 1423829400000.0], [45, 1423829700000.0], [35, 1423830000000.0], [33, 1423830300000.0], [22, 1423830600000.0], [45, 1423830900000.0], [70, 1423831200000.0], [34, 1423831500000.0], [30, 1423831800000.0]]},{\"target\": \"login\", \"datapoints\": [[5000, 1423825200000.0], [100000, 1423825500000.0], [3000, 1423825800000.0], [20000, 1423826100000.0], [15, 1423826400000.0], [50, 1423826700000.0], [11, 1423827000000.0], [50, 1423827300000.0], [60, 1423827600000.0], [50, 1423827900000.0], [60000, 1423828200000.0], [10000, 1423828500000.0], [100000, 1423828800000.0], [20000, 1423829100000.0], [40000, 1423829400000.0], [45000, 1423829700000.0], [35000, 1423830000000.0], [33000, 1423830300000.0], [22000, 1423830600000.0], [45000, 1423830900000.0], [70000, 1423831200000.0], [34000, 1423831500000.0], [30000, 1423831800000.0]]}]}")
```

I need to convert this json data to data frame with the correct column names:

I tried this:

```
x<-fromJSON(x)
(x <- lapply(x, function(x) { as.data.frame(x) }))
(x <- do.call(rbind, x))
dat<-cbind(data.frame(x$data[[1]]),data.frame(x$data[[2]])
```

but I dont see the heading cpu and login. I need to be able to refer to each column by the dat$cpu or dat$login

I get something like this:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(5, 10, 3, 20, 15, 50, 11, 50, 60, 50, 60, 
10, 100, 20, 40, 45, 35, 33, 22, 45, 70, 34, 30), X2 = c(1423825200000, 
1423825500000, 1423825800000, 1423826100000, 1423826400000, 1423826700000, 
1.423827e+12, 1423827300000, 1423827600000, 1423827900000, 1423828200000, 
1423828500000, 1423828800000, 1423829100000, 1423829400000, 1423829700000, 
1.42383e+12, 1423830300000, 1423830600000, 1423830900000, 1423831200000, 
1423831500000, 1423831800000), X1 = c(5000, 1e+05, 3000, 20000, 
15, 50, 11, 50, 60, 50, 60000, 10000, 1e+05, 20000, 40000, 45000, 
35000, 33000, 22000, 45000, 70000, 34000, 30000), X2 = c(1423825200000, 
1423825500000, 1423825800000, 1423826100000, 1423826400000, 1423826700000, 
1.423827e+12, 1423827300000, 1423827600000, 1423827900000, 1423828200000, 
1423828500000, 1423828800000, 1423829100000, 1423829400000, 1423829700000, 
1.42383e+12, 1423830300000, 1423830600000, 1423830900000, 1423831200000, 
1423831500000, 1423831800000)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X1", 
"X2"), row.names = c(NA, -23L), class = "data.frame")
```

Is there a better way to convert this json to data frame with the correct column names?

I need my output to be like this:

```
structure(list(cpu = c(5, 10, 3, 20, 15, 50), cpu.time = c(1423825200000, 
1423825500000, 1423825800000, 1423826100000, 1423826400000, 1423826700000
), login = c(5000, 1e+05, 3000, 20000, 15, 50), login.time = c(1423825200000, 
1423825500000, 1423825800000, 1423826100000, 1423826400000, 1423826700000
)), .Names = c("cpu", "cpu.time", "login", "login.time"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What what does the "correct" data.frame look like? Looks like you have two values for each cpu and each login. That would give 4 different columns right? What do you want each of those columns to be named?

Comment: @MrFlick, if you look at the x vector at the beginnin of the post, the fist value is cpu (which has value time pair) and the second value is login (which also have value date pair). When I am forming the data frame, I need to be able to dynamically name the columns. Regardles of it is cpu or login. It could be something else.

Comment: That still doesn't clarify what you want as output. Do you want one data.frame with 4 columns? Something like: `xx<-jsonlite:::fromJSON(x); Reduce(cbind, Map(function(n, d) setNames(data.frame(d), paste(n,c("cnt","time"), sep=".")), xx$data[[1]], xx$data[[2]]))`?

Comment: @MrFlick, almost. Is it possible to get rid of not include .cnt in the column name, just have cpu and login?

Comment: Edit your question to show your desired output

Comment: @MrFlick, I really appreciate this, this is great. As I have tried to convey, I need column names to be dynamically assign. What I mean is this. In this case my json node or target name is cpu, but it may be something else like transaction or memory etc. When I convert json to data frame, column names need to be drived from the target names. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
xx <- jsonlite:::fromJSON(x)
Reduce(cbind, Map(function(n, d) 
    setNames(data.frame(d), c(n, paste0(n,".time"))), 
    xx$data[[1]], xx$data[[2]])
)
```

which returns

```
  cpu     cpu.time  login   login.time
1   5 1.423825e+12   5000 1.423825e+12
2  10 1.423825e+12 100000 1.423825e+12
3   3 1.423826e+12   3000 1.423826e+12
4  20 1.423826e+12  20000 1.423826e+12
5  15 1.423826e+12     15 1.423826e+12
6  50 1.423827e+12     50 1.423827e+12
```