# Convert JSON URL to R Data Frame

Tags: json, r, dataframe

I'm having trouble converting a JSON file (from an API) to a data frame in R. An example is the URL http://api.fantasy.nfl.com/v1/players/stats?statType=seasonStats&season=2010&week=1&format=json

I've tried a few different suggestions from S/O, including 
[convert json data to data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683769/convert-json-data-to-data-frame-in-r) and various blog posts such as http://zevross.com/blog/2015/02/12/using-r-to-download-and-parse-json-an-example-using-data-from-an-open-data-portal/

The closest I've been is using the code below which gives me a large matrix with 4 "rows" and a bunch of "varables" (V1, V2, etc.). I'm assuming that this JSON file is in a different format than "normal" ones.

```
library(RJSONIO)

raw_data <- getURL("http://api.fantasy.nfl.com/v1/players/stats?statType=seasonStats&season=2010&week=1&format=json")

data <- fromJSON(raw_data)

final_data <- do.call(rbind, data)
```

I'm pretty agnostic as to how to get it to work so any R packages/process are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What package are you using? I see three packages on CRAN with a `fromJSON` function (`rjson`, `RJSONIO`, and `jsonlite`).

Comment: @MichaelChirico Apologies, I'll edit. For this it is RJSONIO but I've tried all three with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing "abnormal" about this JSON, its just not a rectangular structure that fits trivially into a data frame. JSON can represent much richer data structures.

For example (using the `rjson` package, you've not said what you've used):

```
> data = rjson::fromJSON(file="http://api.fantasy.nfl.com/v1/players/stats?statType=seasonStats&season=2010&week=1&format=json")
> length(data[[4]][[10]]$stats)
[1] 14
> length(data[[4]][[1]]$stats)
[1] 21
```

(`data[[1 to 3]]` look like headers)

the "stats" of the 10th element of `data[[4]]` has 14 elements, the "stats" of the first has 21. How is that going to fit into a rectangular data frame? R has stored it in a list because that's R's best way of storing irregular data structures.

Unless you can define a way of mapping the irregular data into a rectangular data frame, you can't store it in a data frame. Do you understand the structure of the data? That's essential.

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman. It sounds like the issue is with me not mapping the JSON -> data frame process (I didn't know one had to do so). I don't know how to yet but will investigate. Thanks!

Comment: Well you only have to do so *if* the JSON is structured deeper than a simple table, which it is here. Quite what the optimal way of structuring the data in R (keep as a list, convert to two data frames with a linking ID) depends on what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 10):

The `jsonlite` package automatically picks up the dataframe:

```
library(jsonlite)
mydata <- fromJSON("http://api.fantasy.nfl.com/v1/players/stats?statType=seasonStats&season=2010&week=1&format=json")

names(mydata$players)
# [1] "id"                 "esbid"              "gsisPlayerId"       "name"              
# [5] "position"           "teamAbbr"           "stats"              "seasonPts"         
# [9] "seasonProjectedPts" "weekPts"            "weekProjectedPts" 

head(mydata$players)
#        id     esbid gsisPlayerId                name position teamAbbr stats.1
# 1  100029     FALSE        FALSE San Francisco 49ers      DEF       SF      16
# 2     729 ABD660476   00-0025940     Husain Abdullah       DB       KC      15
# 3 2504171 ABR073003   00-0019546        John Abraham       LB               15
# 4 2507266 ADA509576   00-0025668       Michael Adams       DB               13
# 5 2505708 ADA515576   00-0022247          Mike Adams       DB      IND      15
# 6 1037889 ADA534252   00-0027610       Phillip Adams       DB      ATL      11
```

You can control this using the `simplify` arguments in `jsonlite::fromJSON()`.

Answer (score 0):

RJson and Jsonlite have similar commands, like fromJSON but depending on the order you load them, they will override each other. For my purposes, rJson structures data much better than JsonLite, so I make sure to load in the correct order/only load Rjson

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer seems more like a comment than a solution. (I know new users aren't able to post comments.)

Answer (score 0):

## jsonlite is load

```
library(jsonlite)
```

## Definition of quandl_url

```
quandl_url <- "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/FB/data.json?auth_token=i83asDsiWUUyfoypkgMz"
```

## Import Quandl data:

```
quandl_data <- fromJSON(quandl_url)
```

## quandl_data in list type

```
quandl_data
```